# Execute function of another file with eval without having to import the file

Tags: python, sockets, server, rpc, serversocket

I'm currently doing a project about sockets in python. 
I have a server class which stores available functions in a dictionary (self.functions) and so I am trying to execute those functions with eval.

```
    def exec_function(self, func, *params):
    if func in self.functions:
        if utils.has_variable_params(self.functions[func]):
            return True, eval(func + "(*params)")
        else:
            string_params = utils.get_params_string(self.functions[func], *params)
            print(string_params)
            return True, eval(func + "("+string_params+")")
    return False, -32601
```

Those functions happen to be in another file (mylib.py) and I can't execute them without having to import the file. 
Do you have any suggestions how I can execute them without having to import the file? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use function objects instead of `eval`: `self.functions[func](*params)` and import them as any other function.

Comment: Furthermore, you can use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) to dynamically import modules from other files.

Comment: @Daniel the problem is I don't want to import any file, I only want to use the functions in the dict and if I register in the server functions from different files I don't want to be importing every single file

Comment: In some way, you have to import the modules. Static or dynamic with `importlib`.

Comment: @Daniel I tried using importlib and didn't work. Is there anyway I can do it without importing, only using the function objects I have stored in the dictionary?

Comment: Show, what you have tried.